# VPN or Proxy or what to serve a specific group of users

Tags: proxy, ip-address, vpn, routes, router

My scenario is this:

I have a web-service (hosted in US) that is being accessed by our users. I have a new users from China and my web-service might get blocked by Great Firewall of China. My question is, is it possible that my web-service will use some kind of proxy or something(i don't know exactly what technology it is) that will have my service a Chinese IP Address (hoping to not get blocked) without having each users (web service consumer) to modify their browser settings of some sort?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you could setup another server (IP) that port forwards to your service. That is a little awkward though, as you could just provide your service via that IP. There's not really a way to automatically proxy a user (that would be scary).

Also consider speed when serving to China. If your potential clientele warrants it, you may consider getting a Chinese I.P. Address & server. There are some tax issues and legal documents to sign though. I actually just went through the process with ChinaNetCloud.

The main thing to get a Chinese server is the SIR form. [Here](http://chinanetcloud.com/sites/default/files/NetCloud_OutsourcingWP20080928_1.pdf) is a sales pitch from CNC... Just remember that China is HUGE and you may even want to co-locate. Even a server in Hong Kong is slow in Beijing. HK is on the other side of the Great Firewall.

Possibly look at this: firewall. https://serverfault.com/questions/147232/port-forwarding-with-multiple-ips

Comment: "Technically, you could setup another server (IP) that port forwards to your service."

-- Can you please give me a nice tutorial link , i cannot find the correct search term to google search it. Thanks!

Comment: You still cant automagically proxy a visitor. They have to be able to get to your IP address in the first place. So, the only option is to obtain an IP on the other side of the wall, and have that machine port forward to your external service-- which isn't guaranteed to get through either.